# Is there a software which finds alternate models for owned sets?

Tags: sets, software, bricklink, alternate-model

I know for example the catalog of BrickLink and now I wonder if there is a software which can calculate from the inventory lists which other models one can build with an owned set?

To more detail: If one owns a set with a lots of parts, there have to be some set with less parts that are included in the big set...

I have now browsed Rebrickable website, but there are only self-made instructions for owned sets. This is nice, but I searched for "original" models, which I can build of my owned sets. Did I made something wrong?

Comment: In your build options, you can select whether or not to include custom models or official lego models. Click "Change build options", then select "Include Official Sets (LEGO)" and "Include Official Sets (LEGO)" or "Include Custom sets (MOC)"

Comment: thank you for this advice!

Answer (score 5):

You're describing rebrickable:

https://rebrickable.com/

Besides official models, also hundreds of fan created models are available.
It's a terrific resource